# Show 3 image and middle image must be active carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this plugin jquery.jcarousellite, trying to active second image is active, I tryied following code
css

```
<div id="jcl-demo">
    <div class="custom-container auto moreItems ">
        <a href="#" class="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <div class="carousel" style="visibility:hidden; left:-5000px;">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/comm-stake-holders.png"></li>
                <li><img src="images/comm-investors.png"></li>
                <li><img src="images/comm-developers.png"></li>
                <li><img src="images/construction.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: kindly show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can specify from which item the carousel should start with `start` property. Remember, the first item in the carousel has a start of 0, and so on.

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        start: 1
    });
});
```

You can read more [here](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/documentation.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    total_li=$(".carousel ul li").length;
    middle_li=(total_li/2)-1;
    $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        start: middle_li
    });
});
```